# JQuery wheel spin onload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have little problem with JQuery.

Am making spinning wheel application. That application start when I click on button.
I want to change that, because my client will determine when wheel to begin.

Most of my configuration is stored in a database but I try with single number **1 = start**, **0 stop**.

My app have this for button click and start:

```
this.cache.wheelSpinBtn = $('.wheel'); 
// test
this.cache.wheelSpin = 1; // 1 auto start 0 False
```

Application start when i press button with class **.wheel**

```
this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) _this.spin();
});
```

But I want to remove the button from the other visitors, and this command is issued in the administration. As I said in my configuration is based

I try without database :

```
if(this.cache.wheelSpin === 1) {
   this.spin();  // if is 1 start spinning
}
```

With database that looks:

```
if(this.cache.wheelSpin === <?php echo $obj->getStatus()?> ) {
   this.spin();  // if is 1 start spinning
}
```

In both cases that is not work when i refresh page.
I just want when i refresh page wheel start spins. If is value 1 and my core know when need to stop.

My applucation code is little compicated and my code is in  and its inposible to use .ready() on only one this.cache.wheelSpin...

Check video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-yi6Sv71rs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: So your question is to make the wheel turns on window onload or what? I really don't understand your issue and posting a video doesn't help much here. Why can't you just trigger click event on window onload?

Comment: I just want to wheel start if value is 1. Whitout pressing button. So if value if 1 after refreshing page wheel must spin.

Comment: If your trying to keep the state of a variable, you should try using session/cookie or adding the state to the url.

Comment: i'd say then use kind of persistent storage as localstorage or cookie and if 1 trigger click event

Comment: I cant bcs that is FB app. Any simple example to autoload this when page loaded. Only admin set value in database